# Show rows that contain a value between two given values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a relatively complex Excel sheet and have come stuck with this problem.

So I have a datasheet that contains building names, their location etc. and then in **COLUMN D** I have the area size of that building. I have a separate sheet called "Control" which will allow the user to control the outputs of the second sheet through drop downs. One area I want them to be able to control is to show/hide rows that contain certain sized buildings. So for example I have a list of sizes such as:

```
0-19,999
20,000-39,999
40,000-59,999
60,000-79,999
80,000-99,999
100,000+
```

With a Show/Hide dropdown in the adjacent cells. If I only select "Show" for 80-99,999 and 100,000+, I only want to be able to see rows of buildings that fall into this category on the second sheet.

I have very basic knowledge of Visual Basic but I think this would be the only way to do such a thing?

Any help would be appreciated! I just need a start and hopefully will be able to work this out.

EDIT:

I have some sort of functionality by using this code as suggested by Jean-Pierre:

```
    If Range("F2").Value = "Yes" Then
Worksheets("Output").Range("$A$2:$AC$198").AutoFilter Field:=4, _
                                Criteria1:=">=0", _
                                Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                Criteria2:="<=19999"
ElseIf Range("F3").Value = "Yes" Then
Worksheets("Output").Range("$A$2:$AC$198").AutoFilter Field:=4, _
                                Criteria1:=">=20000", _
                                Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                Criteria2:="<=39999"
End If
```

However, when "Yes" is selected for both in the control sheet, the output is only showing buildings between 0 and 19,999 in area size, and not 0 to 39,999. If I change both to "No" then it still shows 0 to 19,999 as well. So the functionality is not fully correct. Ideas?

EDIT2:

**CONTROL**

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
Sub ShowBuildings()

Dim wsC As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet    
Set wsC = Worksheets("Control")
Set wsO = Worksheets("Output")

Dim x As Long, sList() As String
x = 0

With wsC

    Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In .Range("F2:F13")

    If rng.Value2 = "Yes" Then

        ReDim Preserve sList(x)
        sList(x) = rng.Offset(, -1)

        x = x + 1

    End If

    Next

End With

With wsO
With .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End With

End Sub
```

JEEPED CODE

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F13")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim v As Long, vSQFTs As Variant
    vSQFTs = Range("E2:G13").Value2
    For v = LBound(vSQFTs, 1) To UBound(vSQFTs, 1)
        vSQFTs(v, 3) = CBool(LCase(vSQFTs(v, 2)) = "Yes")
        If v < UBound(vSQFTs, 1) Then
            vSQFTs(v, 2) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(45))(1))
            vSQFTs(v, 1) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(45))(0))
        Else
            vSQFTs(v, 1) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(43))(0))
            vSQFTs(v, 2) = Rows.Count  '1,048,576 make this larger if you want
        End If
    Next v
    buildingsShowHide vSQFTs
End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Sub buildingsShowHide(aSQFTs As Variant)
Dim a As Long, rw As Long, sqft As Long, sft As String, dSQFTs As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set dSQFTs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Worksheets("Output")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    For rw = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        sqft = .Cells(rw, "D").Value2
        sft = .Cells(rw, "D").Text
        If Not dSQFTs.exists(sft) Then
            For a = LBound(aSQFTs, 1) To UBound(aSQFTs, 1)
                If sqft >= aSQFTs(a, 1) And sqft <= aSQFTs(a, 2) And      aSQFTs(a, 3) Then
                    dSQFTs.Add Key:=sft, Item:=sqft
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next a
        End If
    Next rw

    With .Columns(4)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dSQFTs.keys,      Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End With

dSQFTs.RemoveAll: Set dSQFTs = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: see `Worksheet_Change` event for your control sheet and `AutoFilter`for the data sheet.

Comment: What if more than a single square footage range was indicating **Show**? Should 20,000 - 79,999 be combined if 20,000-39,999, 40,000-59,999 and 60,000-79,999 were **Show**? What about if only 20,000-39,999 and 60,000-79,999 were **Show**?

Comment: If more than a single square footage range indicated show, then it would need to show all rows that complied with that. So if 20,000-39,999 and 60,000-79,999 were the only two saying "Yes", then the output list should only show buildings that fall into either category. So a building that is 19,000 sq ft would show, and so would a 75,000 sq ft building. However, a 40,000 sq ft building would not.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require use the following:

```
If Option1 = True Then
    'Active sheet will become the sheet you want to filter
    'Field 9 refers to the 9th field of the filter range
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$3").AutoFilter Field:=9, _
                                    Criteria1:=">=0", _
                                    Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                    Criteria2:="<=19999"
ElseIf Option2 = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$3").AutoFilter Field:=9, _
                                    Criteria1:=">=20000", _
                                    Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                    Criteria2:="<=39999"
'Remainder of options here

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I define option 1? Would it be: If Range("F2").Value = "Yes" (If F2 is the first "Yes/No" option; "Yes" being confirmation to SHOW rows containing building within the area size). Would this be correct?

Comment: You will need to implement a drop down box or optionbutton probably. Will have a look tomorrow when I'm back at work. Research so long into adding buttons to your excel page using designmode. What you might want to do is have a button which, when pressed, runs the Macro which then checks the desired ranges for each option amd implements the filter on the designated sheet

Comment: Thank you. I've tried using this but it's giving me an error: If Range("F2").Value = "Yes" Then
    Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ouput").Range("$A$2:$AC$198")

Comment: Also, what would the 9th field of the filter range be referring to? The area column is the 4th in the output table

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? If cell F2 says "Yes" then I want to filter rows that contain a value in between 0 and 19999 in column D

Comment: You need to refer to the `Sheet` as well for you to check a specific cell

Comment: I've added some information to my original question, I hope this helps... it is sort of working but not correctly

Comment: You need to refer to the document as well probably. I will test it properly in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "helper column" into column E of  the `Output` tab (call it say, "Area Grouping") that shows the area size grouping for each row that corresponds to the groupings you have on the `Control` tab.

### Output Tab

[image: Output Tab]

### Control Tab

[image: Control Tab]

Then you can loop through all the options on the `Control` tab and load the ones with "Yes" into an array that you can use to filter the Area Grouping column of the `Output` tab with the code below.

```
Sub ShowBuildings()

Dim wsC As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

Set wsC = Worksheets("Control")
Set wsO = Worksheets("Output")

Dim x As Long, sList() As String
x = 0

With wsC

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In .Range("F2:F13")

        If rng.Value2 = "Yes" Then

            ReDim Preserve sList(x)
            sList(x) = rng.Offset(, -1)

            x = x + 1

        End If

    Next

End With


With wsO

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    With .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If x > 0 Then  'checks to see if array is empty because no "yes'" were selected
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Else
            .AutoFilter
        End If

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

### Results of Output (based on selection shown above)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This would work but if I wanted to change the grouping in the future, it would make it quite difficult wouldn't it?

Comment: not necessarilly, if you build the "helper column" with a nested if statement ... like this `=if(D2>20000,"0-19,999",if(And(D2>19999,D2<40000,"20,000-39,9999"...` then all you have to do is adjust the formula once and drag down.

Comment: Thank you. Ok so when I filter the list, it filters out all values, despite F2:F13 all saying "Yes"?

Comment: The only bits I changed were: For Each rng In .Range("F2:F13") because I have more area groupings and: With .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) since Area Grouping is column D and the first data entry is in cell D3

Comment: please update your post with a screen shot of your data (control sheet and output tab) as it is right now. otherwise, it's hard to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Ugh. I tried to fix the embedding for you, but somehow I placed the same picture in both. You can update the control tab by inserting a picture from the options and dragging your screenshot onto the SO dialog box. Your code replacement looks right and it works for me. When you say `it filters out all values` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I fixed the original post. When I say it filters out all values, there is no data entry in my output tab, it's as if everything (F2:F13) is set to "No".

Comment: Whether I set F2 to F13 as Yes or No, it alwyas displays the output like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QKHyN.png

Comment: it has something to do with the formatting of the data in both places, I think. Make sure both F2 to F13 and column D are set to general? Or make them text.

Comment: Tried setting them to text and general and neither changed anything!

Comment: I would ask for a copy of your spreadsheet, but cannot get external links where I am right now.  When you open the filter further to see what is shown in `Text Filter` what does it say? I know it's a bizarre formatting thing, which I have experienced before but cannot recall the exact fix...

Comment: Under Text Filter, it says Custom Filter, and when I click Custom Filter, it shows this: http://i.imgur.com/thhNnM7.png

Comment: link is blank ... can you update your Control Tab picture again. Your original fix did not work, I don't think.

Comment: It's appearing fine for me, there isn't much to see anyway, other than E2:E13 has the area groupings and F2:F13 has Yes in them. That link shows the Custom Filter and it say: Area Grouping: is less than or equal to: 0 then And is selected as a radio button, then it says: is less than or equal to: 19999

Comment: I think it's because the custom filter is not set to "equal to: 0-19999" for example, it's reading it as two numbers, if that makes sense?

Comment: I see it now. I can see through the pictures that there is a difference in the text formatting on both sheets (look at the leading spacing in column D). Copy the format from E2 and paste into column D. Or re-enter the data in column D. Also clear the autofilter completely and run it again. It's not the `Custom Filter` at all. it's a data format issue. The code works smoothly on my end and look how the data matches exactly on my 2 pictures.

Comment: I actually tried this a moment ago and it didn't solve it. The reason for the leading was due to the cell alignment.

Comment: I made some small tweaks to my code to try to and help. Try it now (All references based on your range definitions now.

Comment: Hi Scott, unfortunately this does not resolve anything

Comment: Also, I had another question, how could I incorporate the same concept for London/Rest of UK? So that I could filter that to using the Control sheet. I.E. If I only select "Yes" for London, then only buildings in London would show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96097/discussion-between-scott-holtzman-and-sam-wells).

Answer (score 1):

An [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) run from a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro seems appropriate here.

Right-click the **Control** worksheet's name tab and choose *View Code*. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet2 (Code)*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F7")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim v As Long, vSQFTs As Variant
        vSQFTs = Range("E2:G7").Value2
        For v = LBound(vSQFTs, 1) To UBound(vSQFTs, 1)
            vSQFTs(v, 3) = CBool(LCase(vSQFTs(v, 2)) = "show")
            If v < UBound(vSQFTs, 1) Then
                vSQFTs(v, 2) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(45))(1))
                vSQFTs(v, 1) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(45))(0))
            Else
                vSQFTs(v, 1) = CLng(Split(vSQFTs(v, 1), Chr(43))(0))
                vSQFTs(v, 2) = Rows.Count  '1,048,576 make this larger if you want
            End If
        Next v
        buildingsShowHide vSQFTs
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub buildingsShowHide(aSQFTs As Variant)
    Dim a As Long, rw As Long, sqft As Long, sft As String, dSQFTs As Object
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dSQFTs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Worksheets("Buildings")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            sqft = .Cells(rw, "D").Value2
            sft = .Cells(rw, "D").Text
            If Not dSQFTs.exists(sft) Then
                For a = LBound(aSQFTs, 1) To UBound(aSQFTs, 1)
                    If sqft >= aSQFTs(a, 1) And sqft <= aSQFTs(a, 2) And aSQFTs(a, 3) Then
                        dSQFTs.Add Key:=sft, Item:=sqft
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next a
            End If
        Next rw
        
        With .Columns(4)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dSQFTs.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    End With

    dSQFTs.RemoveAll: Set dSQFTs = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Compare the image below with your own cell ranges and worksheet names. Make any adjustments to the code that are necessary. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your workbook.

[image: square_footage_filter]

Any reselection of the dropdowns in Control!F2:F7 will trigger a refiltering of the Buildings worksheet. The square footage numbers in my Buildings' column D are true numbers formatted as `0 ft²`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried this by changing the range to F2:F13 and then the vSQFTs range to E2:G13 (I'm not sure why this is G?) - but it doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: I've added the code I used based on your code to my original post